# JTCalender delegate method issue with Xcode 8.2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, jtcalendar

I was using xcocde 8 then i was getting only warning as below

> Instance method 'calendar(*:didTouchDayView:)' nearly matches
>   optional requirement 'calendar(*:didTouchDayView:)' of protocol
>   'JTCalendarDelegate'

code for didtouchview

```
  func calendar(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!, didTouchDayView dayView: JTCalendarDayView!) {

    print("touch view is \(self.dateFormatter().string(from: dayView.date))")

    if let data =  dict_events[self.dateFormatter().string(from: dayView.date)]
    {
      let array:[CalenderEventModal] = data
      if array.count>0
      {
        if arr_taskList.count > 0
        {
          arr_taskList.removeAll()
          arr_taskList = array
        }
        self.tableview.reloadData()
        indexpath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        self.tableview.scrollToRow(at: indexpath!, at: .top, animated: true)
      }

    }
  }
```

But when i use this code in Xcode 8.2 then it shows me error as below

> Objective-C method 'calendar:didTouchDayView:' provided by method
>   'calendar(*:didTouchDayView:)' conflicts with optional requirement
>   method 'calendar(*:didTouchDayView:)' in protocol 'JTCalendarDelegate'

Comment: You need to raise this issue with the JTCalendar, also check the github if they have different repo for swift.

Comment: i have done already it but no reply has given

Comment: You need to fork the repo and re-write that method. This would be your last option.